# Android: Display Special Characters

Tags: android, fonts

I would like to display special characters such as: ṁ ṭ m ē. In case they don't display here as well, this is how the four characters should look like: [image: Display of special chars]

In Android, these will display in squares. For other scripts, I am able to come over this problem with using a different font. But in this case setting the font (`TextView.setTypeFace`) will not solve this issue. These characters display correctly in for example OpenOffice (using Arial or Courier New), but inside Android it doesn't even when using the same fonts).

I also tried having the string saved as a unicode encoded string (e.g. in strings.xml: \u1E41 \u1E6D) getting the same result (in the logs they appear as they should). Any ideas?

Comment: testing on Android 2.3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was really only a font issue. It was just hard to find a font that supports all characters I need.

Seeing that Google Translate has no problems with transliteration characters motivated me to make a more thorough search for fonts. Below is a list of useful fonts for this purpose:

- http://guindo.pntic.mec.es/jmag0042/alphaeng.html (extensive but non-free)
- http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/
- http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=FontDownloads
- http://www.mufi.info/fonts/

Comment: You are right, Android does NOT support all unicodes like "\u266B" (♫), also a lot in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Operators.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Jacky: Yes, as I tried to make clear, using a certain font package (ttf) had the desired effect. I used to have this problem with devanagari characters (an Indian script), earlier with the same solution.

Comment: @Jacky: If you need to know how to set the typeface to your textview, here's how: `Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(
    context.getAssets(),
    "path/file.ttf");
  textView.setTypeface(face);`

Answer (score 4):

If these characters are representable in Unicode, then you should be able to use Html.fromHtml() to get the glyph into a TextView, e.g.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#1234;"), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: I guess, you meant "&#1234;" or rather "&#x1234" (for hex values). However, this does not do it either for the characters I need (e.g. &#x1E41). Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.  It sounds as if Android does not have the required font for the language in question.  If you can find the font somewhere, you can include it in the /res/assets folder of your package.  Then use TypeFace to load the font, caching it if you will use it more than once.  E.g.                             Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "your_font.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL);

Comment: In the question I wrote that I tried this too. The strange thing is using the same font as used in some desktop applications (OpenOffice, some editors), where the characters appear correctly, still does not display them correctly inside Android.

Comment: This works in some cases. However, it does NOT work for unicodes like "\u266B" (♫), also a lot in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Operators